# Resolve warning when using the strcmp function of C to compare two elements of different structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, comparison, strcmp

I'm new to programming in C and I'm trying to make a comparison with the elements of two structures. I've this structure:

```
typedef struct tema{
    char * nombreTema;
    int cantSubscript;
    subscript * subscriptores;
}tema;

typedef struct subscriptor{
    struct sockaddr_in * cliente;
} subscriptor;
```

And I've this function:

```
int altaSubscriptor(char* tematica, int puerto, struct sockaddr_in * cliente, lista_temas* listaTemas){

    struct sockaddr_in aux;
    memcpy((void *) &aux, (void*) cliente, sizeof(aux));
    aux.sin_port = htons(puerto);
    aux.sin_family = PF_INET;

    tema* temas = buscarTema(tematica, listaTemas);
    if(temas == NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    int cantSubs = temas->cantSubscript;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < temas->cantSubscript; i++){
        if (strcmp(temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente, &aux) == 0)
            return -1;
    }

    if(cantSubs % BLOQUE == 0){
        temas->subscriptores = realloc(temas->subscriptores, (temas->cantSubscript + BLOQUE) * sizeof(subscript));
    }
    temas->subscriptores[cantSubs] = malloc(sizeof(subscriptor));
    temas->subscriptores[cantSubs]->cliente = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memcpy((void*) temas->subscriptores[cantSubs]->cliente, (void*) cliente, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    temas->subscriptores[cantSubs]->cliente->sin_port = htons(puerto);
    temas->subscriptores[cantSubs]->cliente->sin_family = PF_INET;

    temas->cantSubscript += 1;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I make a comparison between elements of the "subject" structure and the "aux" structure inside the for loop, I get this warning:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct sockaddr_in *' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                if (strcmp(temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente, &aux) == 0)
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:77:25: note: passing argument to parameter '__s1' here
int      strcmp(const char *__s1, const char *__s2);
```

So, it is not clear to me how I have to pass the arguments to the strcmp function.

I apologize for the inconvenience and thank you in advance.

Comment: You are passing pointers to `struct` but pointers to `char` are required. The only such visible in your code are the `struct` member `char *nombreTema` and the function argument `char *tematica` neither of which is passed to `strcmp`.

Comment: Did you read the documentation to [`strcmp()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4.2)?

Answer (score 1):

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct sockaddr_in *' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                if (strcmp(temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente, &aux) == 0)
```

The warning tells you all. `strcmp` expects both parameters to be `char *` pointers.
The `temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente` is `struct sockaddr_in *` type.

`strcmp` is used to compare strings not structures. You may want to write your own `int cmp_sockaddr_in(struct sockaddr_in *a, struct sockaddr_in * b)` functions by comparing all or some structure's members.

```
// Note:
//       struct sockaddr_in {
//           sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
//           in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
//           struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
//       };
//
//       /* Internet address. */
//       struct in_addr {
//           uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
//       };
//
//      in_port_t is equivalent to the type uint16_t as defined in <inttypes.h> 
//
```

example of comparing two `struct sockaddr_in`:

```
int cmp_sockaddr_in(struct sockaddr_in *a, struct sockaddr_in * b);
```

Note: Only two struct members are compared (`sin_family` is required to be `AF_INET` anyway):

```
int cmp_sockaddr_in(struct sockaddr_in *a, struct sockaddr_in * b)
{
  if(  ((a->sin_addr.s_addr ==  b->sin_addr.s_addr)) &&
        (a->sin_port ==  b->sin_port ) 
    )
    return 1; // s_addr and >sin_port are the same 

    return 0; // different sin_addr.s_addr or sin_ports
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning because you're passing pointers of the wrong type to `strcmp` function.

That said, you are right to take warnings seriously, because in that case, casting to `char *` would remove the warning but that isn't the proper way to do it, since you're comparing *binary data*, not *strings* (`strcmp` would end the comparison at the first `\0` character, not what you want: it could either crash if `\0` isn't found within the struct, or find `\0` at start and all comparisons would yield true!)

In that case you have to use `memcmp` instead, just like you did when you copied the memory using `memcpy`. Just do:

```
if (memcmp(temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente, &aux, sizeof(aux)) == 0)
```

but since both variables are of the same type why not just doing:

```
if (*temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente == aux)
```

which lets the compiler does the job for you, and it's way clearer code.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp()` is *only* for comparing null-terminated character strings.  The function call:

```
strcmp(temas->subscriptores[i]->cliente, &aux)
```

makes no sense since *neither* argument is a string.  They have type `struct sockaddr_in*`.

Comment: Minor counter example: "you never need cast to a void*" --> `printf("%p\n", (void *) &some_object);`.  Generally agree: Rarely  a need to cast `void*` for function parameter  that is `void*`.

Comment: Comparing structure contents with `memcmp()` is not a good idea. It is unclear what the OP is trying to achieve with this loop.

Comment: @chqrlie ; I agree - I am recommending nothing; just fixing this specific problem without reference to the larger context.  Far more code than necessary to demonstrate the problem was posted, and it invites all sorts of comment and opinion that was not asked for.  Better perhaps to wait for the next question for the next inevitable problem.

Comment: @chux : Yes variadic function arguments notwithstanding.  Will change to "seldom".  That part should probably not be in teh answer in any case - it is rather a comment unrelated to the specific question.  Far too much code was posted; inviting such comment.  There are no doubt other flaws, but this specific issue was related to the comparison since both compare and assign operations require first-class types.

Comment: I'm afraid you are recommending it: *In C structs are first-class types and can for simple structures (not containing pointers) be compared using == ie memcmp():*.  The question is tagged `c`, comparing with `==` is incorrect, and comparing with `memcmp()` is not good advice: even structs without pointers cannot be safely compared with `memcmp()` if they contain padding, the discussion of which is beyond the skill level of the OP.

Comment: @chqrlie : There was a typo in the statement you quoted.  Is comparing structs with == not well defined in C?  I take the point about padding, but the idiom is common (from a time when structs were not first class).

Comment: @chqrlie : I have deleted the contentious part of the answer.  May improve when I am at a keyboard rather than a phone.  However other answers have similar flaws.

Comment: @Clifford: I'm afraid there is no such idiom: `struct` values can be assigned, passed to and returned from functions, but not compared. I cannot remember a single C compiler with such an extension or atavism. C++ supports operator overloading, so you can define what `s1 == s2` there.